# Saving a Macro-Enabled Workbook from a Template

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I am trying to get Access to save a Macro-Enabled file from a Macro-Enabled Template.

I get the following errors:
1- The Excel Template is hidden using the Application.visible = False in the Thisworkbook section

[image: This is the error message that displays]

2- Then if I click Yes to make a macro-free workbook I get the following run-time error
[image: Yes-Runtime error]

3- If I click no I get this run-time error
[image: NO-Runtime error]

This is the Code that I am using:

```
Workorder = Me.TxtWorkOrder & "_" & Me.TxtActOrder

Set xlapp = New Excel.Application

xlapp.Visible = False
Excel.Application.EnableEvents = False

Set Wb = xlapp.Workbooks.Open("H:\Template and testers\Template\TabletTemplate.xltm")
Set ws = xlapp.Worksheets("Profile")

ws.Activate
    If Me.TxtWorkOCheck = 1 Then
        'workorder
        With ws
            .Range("B1") = Me.TxtWorkOrder
            .Range("B2") = Me.TxtUserID
            .Range("B3") = Me.TxtJobsiteID
            .Range("B4") = Me.CboPlant.Value
            .Range("B5") = Me.CboArea.Value
            .Range("B6") = Me.TxtScaffoldID
            .Range("B7") = Me.TxtActOrder
            .Range("B10") = output
            .Range("B11") = Me.TxtFuncLocation

        End With
    Else
        'sub-workorder
        With ws
            .Range("B8") = Me.TxtWorkOrder
            .Range("B2") = Me.TxtUserID
            .Range("B3") = Me.TxtJobsiteID
            .Range("B4") = Me.CboPlant.Value
            .Range("B5") = Me.CboArea.Value
            .Range("B6") = Me.TxtScaffoldID
            .Range("B9") = Me.TxtActOrder
            .Range("B1") = Me.TxtAssoWorkOrder
            .Range("B10") = output
            .Range("B11") = Me.TxtFuncLocation
            .Range("F1") = 0
        End With
    End If

xlapp.Worksheets("ScaffoldList").Activate
Wb.SaveAs ("H:\ActiveWorkOrders\ToGather\" & Workorder & ".xlsm")
Excel.Application.EnableEvents = True

Wb.Close
Set xlapp = Nothing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually specify the type you're saving it as, specifying the extension isn't enough.

Replace the line giving the error by the following:

`Wb.SaveAs "H:\ActiveWorkOrders\ToGather\" & Workorder & ".xlsm", xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled`

See [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbook-saveas-method-excel) for documentation on the `SaveAs` method

Comment: Well fine then make it that easy! :) Thank you very much Erik.... I did miss that in the MSDN